# Windows: Detecting which IR remote keys are pressed

Tags: windows, remote-control, infrared

I'm looking to customize how my 'Noah Company MediaGate GP-IR02BK' remote control works with XBMC. I've found the file I need to update for XBMC (Keymap.xml), but I now need to find out how each remote button is represented in Windows Vista (the remote code?). So for example, if you press the back button it might be represented as 'esc', or maybe an ASCII char.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

*Update 1* - I've just noticed that the [XBMC Wiki](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Keymap.xml#Universal_Remote_Section) mentions that there is a setting in advancedsettings.xml called `<displayremotecodes>` which instructs XBMC to display the remote code when you press a remote control button. I'll try that when I'm home and feedback what I find here.

*Update 2* - Nuts. Just investigated further and it's [XBox Only](http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=Advancedsettings.xml#.3Cdisplayremotecodes.3E) :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this will work for you, but I use [EventGhost](http://www.eventghost.org/) to control foobar2000 and Media Player Classic with various generic IR remotes and a [USB-UIRT](http://www.usbuirt.com/), you can try to check if it supports your IR receiver and it will display the remote's codes.

Answer (score 0):

You need a program that will display the keystrokes generated by your remote.  I found [this site](http://dan.hersam.com/2009/05/01/how-to-display-keystrokes-for-screencasts-on-windows/) that lists three programs (the first link there appears to be broken though), but there's more programs out there.  This of course presumes that your remote generates keystrokes.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

As it's the living room TV/PC, I'm just waiting for it to become available so I can test what you've suggested :-) It certainly looks promising though.

Comment: I saw your link to my site in the referrer logs and just checked the first link.  It's not broken, but goes directly to the [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) script that shows the keyboard.  Just wanted to clarify.